# VBA Mac 2016 activate does not work anymore

Tags: excel, vba, macos

A macro with the line :
Windows("TradingJournal U.xlsm").Activate
was working perfectly with Mac Excel 2011.
In Mac Excel 2016 it gives the error :
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Any help would be very welcome

Comment: And if you remove the `.xlsm`?

Comment: It works ! Thank you for the solution although I don't understand why the other version was working before and now it is this one. But problem solved !

Comment: Would it display `TradingJournal U.xlsm` in the window caption before, and does it display it that way now?

Comment: What do you call "window caption" ? Before on Mac I used, in the file's preferences, to mask the extension .xlsm ; with the new Office, since the macro was not working, I tried to show it, but with no result."

Comment: I call window caption the name of the file as it appears in the middle of the window caption. Does it have the extension, and did it have it in Excel 2011?

Comment: It does not show the extension in the window caption, although I now unmask the extension. With 2011, it didn't show either but then I was masking the extension.